# htaccess URL rewrite space replacement

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

**EDIT NOTE: Modified code to Documentroot**

I am doing rewrite rules for a client's website and I started with my own website's blog rewrite rules, as they kinda match the customer needs. Now that every rules are modified to the client needs, I'm glad it is working super fine. Here is the final look;

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# executes repeatedly as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s.*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

#Rewrite des urls blog
RewriteRule fashion/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)-([0-9]+) fashion/blogpost.php?brand=$1&url=$2&id=$3

#Rewrite des urls brands
RewriteRule fashion/brand/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)-([0-9]+) fashion/brand.php?brand=$1&id=$2

#Rewrite des urls shop brands
RewriteRule fashion/shop/brands/([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)-([0-9]+) fashion/shopbrand.php?brand=$1&id=$2

#Rewrite des urls shop category
RewriteRule fashion/shop/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+) fashion/shopcategory.php?url=$1&id=$2

#Enlever l'extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] 

ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/fashion/404.php

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.php$
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^24\.201\.45\.57
#RewriteRule $ /maintenance.php [R=302,L]
```

I wanted to avoid having spaces issues with blogpost titles or brand names, so I did some searches and added a `\s` in my rules. It works fine, as this replace spaces by `%20`, so now the blogpost titles containing spaces are now accessible but I would like spaces to turn into dashes - and I cannot get it right.

There are many articles available that speaks about turning spaces into dashes but after testing a couple of them, I found out I have difficulties matching them rules to my existing rules.

Any tips or explanations will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert space to `-` you can use these 2 rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
# executes repeatedly as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S*\s.*)$" /$1-$2 [L,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" /$1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @anubhava, works pretty fine as the spaces turns into dashes, thanks a lot. But now, when I try to access an URL containing a variables with spaces (who is now changed into a dash), it removes a part of the path, before blog/ or brand/. I've been trying to adjust that for about an hour and more and I'm screwed lol Many thanks for your help !

Comment: That can only happen if 1. These rules are not first rules below `RewriteEngine On` OR 2. You place these rules in a sub directory of `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: These rules are right below `RewriteEngine On` and the .htaccess is place in the same directory as the files, otherwise I would already had problem before adding these two lines. Tested Chrome39, FF35, IE11.

Comment: Okay, I placed the .htaccess in the actual `DocumentRoot` and modified my actual rewrite rules to match and you're right, the path remains perfect. When I access a link that normally contain spaces, the URL is perfectly written, but now is an Internal Server Error 500. Please see my actual rules I modified in the main question.

Comment: OH ! Never mind that ! The`\s` I added direct in the rewrite rules were corrupting it. Now it works perfect. Thanks !

Comment: Anubhava, oh and if by any mean you have some tips about escaping apostrophes (single quotes), I'll be more than grateful. As in this line `RewriteRule fashion/blog/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([0-9]+) fashion/blogpost.php?brand=$1&url=$2&id=$3`, I tried escaping it by `([a-zA-Z0-9\'\-]+)` but it does not work.

Comment: Single quote usually doesn't require escaping as far as I know

Comment: I'm actually reading a lot on that subject and it seems to be a casual practise. As a `GET` variable can show up in the URL as `/blog/i'm-a-title`, but it cuts at `/blog/i`.

Comment: After a couple read on SO, I tried a couple variations of this line like `([a-zA-Z0-9_'\-]+)` or `([a-zA-Z0-9\'\-]+)` to allow single quote in the url, but issue appears to be somewhere else. This case is def taking me time lol. I'll keep updated with details when I'll find out for others to get what happened.