# How to handle (REAL) blank space in Apache?

Tags: apache, http, curl, encode, space

I know there are many questions like that in stackoverflow. But it is actually different :)

My problem is that Apache (2.4.6) just cannot handle white spaces in a url for instance aspecially used by cURL. Well consider I have a URL like following:

http://10.0.0.1:1234/Some Service/Root?func=getMessage

IF I browse this URL in any popular browser, they change the white space (' ') to %20. And in that way Apache can handle the request (or wget also does so).

However, when I use cURL, it does not change to %20 and in that case Apache return Error 400. I think the reason is, in the end of the GET Url, there is a white space and then specifies the  used HTTP protocol comes.
such as:
GET Some Service/Root?func=getMessage HTTP1.1

The problem is I cannot touch or perform any update on cURL site. For example, I cannot perform a sed operation before cURL  request. So consider like cURL site is like a blackbox. I have no control on that site. **Therefore, I really have to solve this problem only in Apache. Unfortunately, It is the only option for me.**

RewriteRules that I found work with if URL contains %20 instead of real white space (' '). For example \s only for if I write down %20 in the curl request. For example:
curl -v "http://10.0.0.1:1234/Some**%20**Service/Root?func=getMessage"

But if I use like:
curl -v "http://10.0.0.1:1234/Some Service/Root?func=getMessage"
then it gets Erro 400 because of the space.

For example [following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095656/htaccess-url-rewrite-space-replacement) for %20 exists if there is one space or more then one:

#executes repeatedly as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S* .*)$" $1+$2 [N,NE]

#executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI

RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" /$1+$2 [L,R=302,NE]

So my link may not as simple as following: 
http://10.0.0.1:1234/Some Service/Root?func=getMessage

Probably it may include one space :) but there will be more than one parameters like
http://10.0.0.1:1234/Some Service/Root?func=doSomething&id=123&pid=123&message=blabla&name=john&surname=doe

But in any case, ofcourse, I need also  prevent possible problems if there is more then one blank.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't "solve" the problem in the server. You need to fix the curl invocation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Nginx can handle blanks or white spaces. Nginx does not give 400.